# Same icon for different apps

Tags: iphone, ios6, itunes

I have designed 3 apps in multiple languages, but the icons are same for all 3 apps. Will Apple reject the apps because of this reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the same icon for the free version of my apps and for the paid one, so there is no problem with that.

But as mike-dutka says, you should create only one app and localize it to multiple languages

Answer (score 1):

A I understand, You have 3 apps with identical functionality but with different languages. In this case You should localize ONE application for 3 different languages instead of creating 3 different applications. Look at this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial).

Comment: That is not possible now because, Its all ready designed depends on the languages ....

Answer (score 0):

**Quote from the App Store Resource Center:**

> 2.20 Developers "spamming" the App Store with many versions of similar Apps will be removed from the iOS Developer Program

Apple doesn't want you to create multiple apps with the same feature. You have to localize a single app instead of creating multiple apps.